# Ubuntu 14.04 lost wlan0 connection after a certain time

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet, ifconfig

My computer is running Ubuntu 14.04 without GUI. The `wlan0` connection is working fine (in the first 5 mins or so) every time I start the computer.

Here are the `ifconfig` and `iwfonfig` output at the beginning:

```
ifconfig wlan0
wlan0    Link encap:Ethernet Hwaddr 48:51:b7:aa:7d:23
         inet addr:192.168.128 Bcast:192.168.8.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
         inet6 addr: fe80::4a51:b7ff:feaa:7d23/64 Scope:Link
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
         RX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:81 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
         RX bytes:6970 (6.9 KB)  TX bytes:12962 (12.9 KB)
iwconfig wlan0
wlan0    IEEE 802.11abgn ESSID:"STAR2"
         Mode:Managed Frequency:5.805 GHz Access Point: D0:17:C2:E9:EE:68
         Bit Rate=12 Mb/s     Tx-Power=22 dBm
         Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
         Power management:on
         Link Quality=70/70 Signal level=-31 dBm
         Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
         Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:19  Missed beacon:0
```

However, after running for about 5 mins, the computer will suddenly loose the `wlan0` connection automatically. And the only way that I can reestablish the connection is by rebooting the computer.

Here is the `ifconfig` output after losing the connection.
It will lose the connection no matter if I operate it or not.

```
ifconfig wlan0
wlan0   Link encap:Ethernet Hwaddr 48:51:b7:aa:7d:23
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
        RX packets:30197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:42844 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:2019154 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:22009263 (22.0 MB)
```

Thank you so much for any kind of help!

Comment: your Ubuntu is 4 years old. In case what you are seeing is not a HW but a driver problem, then maybe using a newer Ubuntu with a newer linux kernel with newer WiFI drivers would solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks! But this isn't my personal computer, I can't update update to a new version. Any other suggestion?

Comment: have a look at `/var/log/*`  can you find any entries there from the time when the computer lost the wlan connection? You should be able to find out when precisely the computer lost the connection by running something like this: `while ping -c 1 8.8.8.8; do true; done; date`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my problem is because I installed the internet manager on the Ubuntu server, after uninstalling the internet manager and reconfiguring the internet settings problem solved.